# Soma dos números componentes

Tags: java

Estou tentando solucionar o seguinte problema usando `DESVIO CONDICIONAL COMPOSTO`. Pporém não imagino como faço o calculo dos numeros que compõem o algarismo

> Requisitar um valor inteiro ao usuário entre 100 e 999. Se o valor lido for menor de 500, apresentar a soma entre seus números componentes. Caso contrário, apresentar a subtração de seus componentes.

Apenas sei que devo usar `IF` e `ELSE`, onde irei colocar essa condição

```
if(nb > 500 ) {
```

para que ocorra a soma dos números componentes.

O que quebrei a cabeça mas realmente não consegui chegar a uma conclusão é como irei realizar a soma!

Por exemplo, se o número é 328, como irei somar os números 3, 2 e 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ler o número do usuário:

   ```
   Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
   int numero = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());
   ```
2. Certificar-se que o número está ok:

   ```
   if (numero < 100 || numero > 999) {
       System.out.println("Esse número não serve.");
       return;
   }
   ```
3. Separar os componentes:

   ```
   int centenas = numero / 100;
   int dezenas = numero / 10 % 10;
   int unidades = numero % 10;
   ```

Daqui para frente, tenho certeza que você já sabe como fazer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use o split para transformar o valor em um array de valores e faça um loop para ler e somar

```
  String[] array = numeroQueOUsuarioDigitar.split("");

  int total = 0;

  if(Integer.parseInt(numeroQueOUsuarioDigitar) < 500) {
      for(String e : array) {
          total += Integer.parseInt(e);
      }
  } else {
      for(String e : array) {
          total -= Integer.parseInt(e);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Nossa fiquei ainda mais confusa agora!

Comment: o Exercicio na verdade é apenas com If e Else..

Comment: Como assim só com if e else? O que não entendeu?

Comment: Vc me passou uma resoluçao com For,porém para esse exercicio so devo usar If(condição) e Else{ instrução
Devo usar apenas :SE uma condição é VERDADEIRA,
ENTÃO desvia e realiza as instruções vinculadas a condição verdadeira
SENÃO, caso essa condição seja FALSA,
desvia e realiza as instruções vinculadas a condição falsa

Comment: Pelo que entendi da pergunta a dúvida era como fazer a soma dos algarismos de um número e é isso que o código faz, agora só colocar o if para o loop somar e else para o inverso. Entendi errado a pergunta?

Comment: Exatamente Guilherme!
Se o número por exemplo for 328 ,devo somar o três números para chegar no resultado!

Comment: Então, é o que o código faz, o split divide a string de forma a gerar um array com 3 elementos, depois é feito um loop para somar cada item do array a variável total. Já testou?

Comment: e isso daria certo para qualquer numero? Pois o usuario vai digitar o numero,e a parti dai que terei que ler o que foi digitado e fazer o desvio da condicional!

Comment: Sim, mas se o valor da variável não for um número vai gerar um exceção ao tentar converter

Comment: irei tentar então!Até amanhã venho aqui e digo se deu certo!

Comment: Editei a resposta com um exemplo mais completo

Answer (score 0):

Quebra o valor em substrings e volta pra int.

```
    if(nb > 500 ) {
        String aux = Integer.toString(i);
        //TRANSFORMA O NUMERO EM STRING
        int un = Integer.parseInt(aux.substring(0, 1));
        //PEGA O PRIMEIRO CRACTER E TRANSFORMA EM INT
        int de = Integer.parseInt(aux.substring(1, 2));
        //PEGA O SEGUNDO CRACTER E TRANSFORMA EM INT
        int ce = Integer.parseInt(aux.substring(2, 3));
        //PEGA O TERCEIRO CRACTER E TRANSFORMA EM INT
        int total = ce + de + un;
        //SOMA OS COMPONENTES
    }else{
        String aux = Integer.toString(i);
        //TRANSFORMA O NUMERO EM STRING
        int un = Integer.parseInt(aux.substring(0, 1));
        //PEGA O PRIMEIRO CRACTER E TRANSFORMA EM INT
        int de = Integer.parseInt(aux.substring(1, 2));
        //PEGA O SEGUNDO CRACTER E TRANSFORMA EM INT
        int ce = Integer.parseInt(aux.substring(2, 3));
        //PEGA O TERCEIRO CRACTER E TRANSFORMA EM INT
        int total = ce - de - un;
        //SUBTRAI OS COMPONENTES
    }
```

É um código bem iniciante, porém assim você faz usando apenas if e else

Comment: Trabalhar com `String`s para resolver problemas matemáticos não é uma boa ideia.

Comment: Mas ele passa para int antes de fazer a soma, então não faz diferença, a string é só para quebrar o que foi digitado em 3 números diferentes.